# How to perform incremental operator in django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to fetch the number unread messages in a chat, It works fine in the django shell but i ran into a problem in the template because i cant use incremental operator

In the django shell, i used the following codes

```
# After importing the required models
unread = 0 
for message in chat.messages.all():
    if message.read != True:
       unread += 1
```

This works fine

In the template, I used the code below

```
{%for message in chat.messages.all %} 
             {% with unread=0 %}  
             {% if message.read != True %} 
                  {{unread+=1}}
             {% endif %}
             {% endwith %}
     <span class="badge badge-light badge" style="margin-top: 27px; font-size: 2.5em; float:right; border-radius: 1.0rem;">{{unread}}</span>

{%endfor%}
```

I want to be able to output the number of unread messages like i could in the django shell

Comment: Why would you try figure this out on the front-end? Just pass it to the template from your view. If you're already passing the unread messages, take the length of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to increment. Just count the unread messages in the view and pass it to the template. You don't need the for loop in the template.

**view**

```
unread = chat.messages.filter(read=False).count()
```

**template**

```
<span ...>{{ unread }}</span>
```